# Nested items control. But child item control should display based on specific condtion in wpf

Tags: wpf

WPF: In Items control, I want to display another items control. But, I want to display the child items control values only for specific set of items of parent items control based on some conditions as shown in the image below. Please let me know, how can we do this.
[Nested items control with specific condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7cPn.png)

More details:

I’ve an items control, based on items in the items control; I will draw rectangular boxes in UI. I.e. each item in the items control represents one rectangular box and all these rectangular boxes are represented in sequence (one after the other in UI).

Now, I’ve one more collection of numbers (such as 10,20,30,40 etc.). These numbers I want to represent as time scale below particular consecutive rectangular boxes. i.e. Let’s say, I’ve 10 items in my parent items control then there will be 10 rectangular boxes represented in the UI. Now, I want to represent one time scale at the bottom of 4th and 5th rectangular box only based on my parent item type (i.e. 4th and 5th box will have one common time scale from 10 to 100 (it’s not independent time scale i.e. one horizontal line below 4th and 5th items i.e. horizontal line starts below 4th and ends below 5th Item. and this line shows values 10 to 100 in sequence)). 
Similarly, I might need to represent the one more common time scale below 8th, 9th and 10th items only (i.e. this horizontal line starts with 10 and might end with value 200.).

[This diagram explains details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65pYY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please give an specific example and include it in the question instead of linking an image. Also, from the Image I can't see, what your conditions would be.

Comment: As you asked updated the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea would be, to have a sub-collection with part of the items and common attached extra information instead of stretching the extra information over a range of items.

I suppose you have a viewmodel, holding your items. You can implement a collection of subitems and a single item with a common base class (`ItemBase` below)

```
public class ItemBase : BaseViewModel
{
}

public class SubItemCollection : ItemBase
{
    private IEnumerable<ItemBase> _SubItems;
    public IEnumerable<ItemBase> SubItems
    {
        get { return _SubItems; }
        set { _SubItems = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private string _CommonText;
    public string CommonText
    {
        get { return _CommonText; }
        set { _CommonText = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class LeafItem : ItemBase
{
    private string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set { _Text = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

I use `BaseViewModel` as a base class, where things like `INotifyPropertyChanged` are handled.

In your XAML, define a template for each item-type as a resource. For the collection type, display additional information below the items

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LeafItem}">
        <Border Margin="3" Padding="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubItemCollection}">
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" BorderBrush="Green">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
            <Separator BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommonText}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Finally, somewhere in your XAML, populate a list of `ItemBase` elements

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderBrush="Green">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

You can test this with the following data context:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ItemBase _Items;
    public ItemBase Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set { _Items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            data = new MyViewModel();
            data.Items = new ItemBase[]
            {
                new LeafItem()
                {
                    Text="Item 1"
                },
                new SubItemCollection()
                {
                    SubItems = new ItemBase[]{
                        new LeafItem()
                        {
                            Text="SubItems 2.1"
                        },
                        new LeafItem()
                        {
                            Text="SubItems 2.2"
                        }
                    },
                    CommonText = "Extra"
                },
                new LeafItem()
                {
                    Text="Item 3"
                }
            };
            DataContext = data;
        }
    }
// ...
```

Comment: This implementation results in each item will have independent sub items collection. But required is two or more items need to have one common sub items collection based on type of item. i.e. in this example second item will have subitems 2.1,2.2. but what is required is two or more items need to have one common sub items collection based on type of item. (I have updated question with little more details for your understanding.)

Comment: @jkalyansagar Now is a good time to update the question with all the information (including a code sample) that you already have. I won't work on my answer based on a vague destription.

Comment: @jkalyansagar Updated.